# JarFile runtime loader

Tags: java, jar

I have a jarFile and I want to load it at runtime.
for eg I have a method which receive jarFile and I want load that jar during runtime.

```
 public void runTestCase   (String ClassName    , JarFile jarfile){
//load jar file. 
}
```